# Alamofire: Use of unresolved identifier 'JSONEncoding'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, alamofire

After installing a new pod and deleting it later, when compiling I get the following error: Use of unresolved identifier 'JSONEncoding'

I'm using Alamofire (4.3) with cocoapods (1.1.1) and Xcode 8.2.1 with Swift 3.

I already tried the following and it didn't work:

- Delete Derrived Data
- Clean the project
- Clean work directory
- Install Alamofire again

  `Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
      switch response.result {
          case .success(let value):
              let json = JSON(value)
              let token = json["value"].stringValue
              completion(true, token)
          case .failure(let error):
              print(error)
              completion(false, nil)
      }
  }`

Comment: Latest Alamofire 4 need cocoapods 1.2 to update the library , try update the cocoapods

Comment: @ArafinRussell updated my cocoapods, executed pod install again and still got the error

Comment: share your code please

Comment: @ArafinRussell code shared

Comment: it would be better if you could share the **baseURL** and **parameters** , nevertheless try **URLEncoding.default** instead

Comment: I had a similar error. Did you import Alamofire in your class?

Comment: I believe `response.result.success` was changed to `response.result.isSuccess`

Comment: @ArafinRussell it gives me the same the same error the I change it to URLEnconding.

Comment: @JuanCurti Yes, I do have Alamofire imported in the class

Comment: @rmp the error still happens when I eliminate the code inside the closure. I Don''
t think that is the problem.

Comment: Oh, it also looks like you are missing the `headers` argument. So it should be like this: `alamoFireManager.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)`

Comment: @rmp Isn't that optional? I used that request and it worked before; is after installing a new pod and uninstalling it that I get the error.

Comment: It will be `nil` by default, I prefer to set it so I know whats being passed.